# Django Testing Errors

Tags: python, django, testing

I'm trying to write test for my django appliation, and I've come accross an error that I just can't explain. For some reason I get an error for this piece of code

```
self.client.login(email='example@comcast.net', password='password')
resp = self.client.get(reverse('task:accept_bid', 
    kwargs={'task_pk' : 8, 'bid_pk' : 6}
    ))
```

But when I do this I get an error (the same code I just don't login)

```
resp = self.client.get(reverse('task:accept_bid', 
    kwargs={'task_pk' : 8, 'bid_pk' : 6}
    ))
```

Here's the traceback that I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/AdamC/projects/WorkStudy/workstudy/tasks/tests.py", line 37, in test_this
kwargs={'task_pk' : 8, 'bid_pk' : 6}
  File "/Users/AdamC/projects/Environment/WorkStudy-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 473, in get
    response = super(Client, self).get(path, data=data, **extra)
   File "/Users/AdamC/projects/Environment/WorkStudy-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 280, in get
    return self.request(**r)
  File "/Users/AdamC/projects/Environment/WorkStudy-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 444, in request
    six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/AdamC/projects/Environment/WorkStudy-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdamC/projects/Environment/WorkStudy-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 22, in _wrapped_view
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdamC/projects/WorkStudy/workstudy/tasks/views.py", line 44, in accept_a_bid_view
    """)
TypeError: error() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Here's the accept_bid_view code

```
@login_required
def accept_a_bid_view(request, **kwargs):
    task=Task.objects.get(pk=kwargs['task_pk'])

    if task.creator == request.user and task.accepted_bid == None:
        bid = Bid.objects.get(pk=kwargs['bid_pk'])
        task.accepted_bid = bid
        task.worker = bid.bidder
        task.accepted = True
        task.accepted_date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
        task.save()
        messages.success(request,"Congrats you've accepted a bid I'm proud of you")
    if bid.bidder.email_notifactions:
        send_mail(' Notification',
            "Someone accepted your bid",
            EMAIL_HOST_USER,
            [task.creator.email],
            fail_silently=False)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('task:task_list'))
    else:
        messages.error("""It looks as if this task has already been accepted
         or maybe you're not the creator, but why would you being clicking 
         buttons then... (The NSA is watchig you)
         """)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
```

Comment: Can we view the code for `accept_a_bid_view`? Looks like a code path that only gets used when you don't login calls a function named `error` with invalid parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add the `request` to

```
messages.error("""It looks as if this task has already been accepted
         or maybe you're not the creator, but why would you being clicking 
         buttons then... (The NSA is watchig you)
         """)
```

it should look as

```
messages.error(request, """It looks as if this task has already been accepted
         or maybe you're not the creator, but why would you being clicking 
         buttons then... (The NSA is watchig you)
         """)
```

Comment: You're a saint, I can't believe I missed that I was looking in my test code the whole time.